# Another way to say "a measure of how easy it is" to do something?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm faced with the task of writing a slightly informal technical paper, where I'd define more than a dozen terms, all ending in "-bility". Examples: portability, maintainability, comprehensibility, etc., etc., etc.

In essence, those are all instances of the concept "a measure of how easy it is to do [something]". But I'm afraid that the text will get repetitive if I start all definitions the same way.

Would there be other phrases with a similar meaning that I could use in this context?

Thanks,

**Edit #1**: Shorter phrases with the same or similar meaning would be a plus...

**Edit #2**: The finishes text will look somewhat like a dictionary, e.g.:

- **Portability** is a measure of how easy it is to...
- **Maintainability** is a measure of how easy it is to...
- **Comprehensibility** is a measure of how easy it is to...

so, this is where the repetition comes from.

Comment: How about ***can be** [ported, maintained, understood, etc.]?* If you want to ring the changes, ***easily** ported*, or ***easy to** port*, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that would definitely work, thank you very much. Do you mean something along the lines of "a measure of how much a system is easy to port", "a measure of how easily a system can be ported"?

Comment: If I were reading an instruction manual, rephrasings for the sake of avoiding repetitiveness would start me worrying what subtleties signalled by the changes in terminology I was missing. 'Portability' is often used to mean 'ease of being carried' rather than 'the measure of how easy the thing is to carry'. A typewriter is not 75% portable.

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth, "ease of being [extended/modified/reused]" all sound great. Regarding portability, this has a very specific meaning in the context of software engineering. And believe it or not, we often need to assign numbers/probabilities to all those properties, called a system's "functional attributes". Still, I'd like to avoid the feel of an "instruction manual" on this text. If the reader gets a firm grasp on the basic concepts, and the text is still enjoyable, I'd be more than content.

Comment: @Edwin: Good point. The *portability* and *maintainability* of ***software*** (which is what I had in mind), are very different attributes to those implied when the same words are applied to, for example, ***laptop computers***.

Comment: You offtopicers.

Comment: @rick: I think even if your text is intended to be "slightly informal", it would probably be a *good* idea if all your "measurable/gradeable attributes" are structurally similar. Most likely your readers would find the text easier to grasp if they notice quickly that all your *xxxxability* terms are used in the same way, so that *high xxxxability* or *scores only 3 out of 10 for xxxxability* always has the same general sense, and they only need to take note of the specfic *xxxx* in each case. Variety for the sake of it is good for food/entertainment, but not for information transfer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, EdwinAshworth, good point. I guess I'll be less uptight about repetition in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some synonymous phrases for you:

> how much effort it takes
>
> how easy it is
>
> the time *[or effort]*  required to
>
> the [amount of] work required
>
> how long you can expect to
>
> how easy *[or hard]* you'll find it to
>
> how much time you'll spend

Comment: Thanks, "how much effort" and "the amount of work" are great for me.

Answer (score 3):

I hesitate to say it for a technical document, but could you use Ease?

**Ease of maintenance.**

**Migrate data with ease.**

Etc.

You could also just mix it up a bit by rephrasing the sentences to drop the -ability part.  So maintainability could be "easy to maintain", "ease of maintenance", "the client or current contractor will be able to maintain the *_* with no difficulty" etc.

Comment: @rick - My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **[facility](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/facility)**

> ease of action or performance; freedom from difficulty

Or **[accessibility](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accessibility)**

> ```
> 1. the fact of being easy to reach, get to, or enter:
> ```
>
> *Mt Kinabalu's popularity lies in its accessibility*
>
> *the easy accessibility of the area*
>
> ```
> 2. the fact of being easy to use or obtain
> ```
>
> *Declining prices have improved accessibility*
>
> *the quality and accessibility of health care*
>
> ```
> 3. the fact of being easy enough to understand and appreciate
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't choose the words ending with "-bility", I need to define them... Edited my question to make this point clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** succumb to what Fowler termed [elegant variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elegant_variation) in technical documents!

Varying the style of a series of definitions without good cause leads the reader to think that there is something different in their substance. The way to avoid such a long phrase being repeted is to include it just a single time, e.g. something *along the lines of*:

> The following technical terms indicate *the ease of performing various
> tasks*:
>
> **Portability**:        carrying
> **Maintainability**:    upkeep
> **Comprehensibility**:  understanding
> …

but with the definitions tabbed out (which SE markup does not allow me to mix with bold) for ease of reading.

I leave it to the individual to find the most suitable form for the words I have italicized. My concern is on how to present an acceptable readable alternative to what I (as a technical writer) regard as the misguided idea of variation in the definitions.